# How do we fast during a kafara?

Tags: sawm, kaffarah

I want to fast for the days in Ramadan that I did not fast, as a kid.

I have heard I can do neeyat (intention) of kafara for all of my missed fasts during my life since it became obligatory for me and then fast for 60 days in just one year.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Alsalam Alaykum brothe,
First of all you must estimate the days that you did not fast.
And the intent to resolve it.
It may be 60, less or more.
The most important thing is that you do not interrupt your fast in making up the obligatory fasting.
Regarding to the Kaffara, you decide and fast according to your ability, and Allah knows what is in your heart and your ability. Allah does not burden a soul but its power.
see here https://islamqa.info/en/google-search?q=ramadan+kafara&search_engine=google